Indian movie where middle-aged family man doubts everything
I would like to get the name of a movie I saw on Netflix (before closing my account), about a middle-aged family man in India who, after finding out the rumors people were spreading about his daughter's boyfriend were false, begins to doubt everything -- including everything from the existence of the gods, to what the callers to his workplace said when they tried to book travel plans with his travel agency, to what day of the week it is, and so on.
I do not speak Hindi and have not been able find this movie through English-language internet searching.

Do you know release date of that movie?

I think it was from the last few years -- 2013 or 2014.

Two option coming to my mind, Bride and Prejudice 2004 and The Other End of the Line but few more too. Please narrow it a bit by more details.

I don't think it was either of those movies. The focus was on the father, not the daughter. Also, I think the title began with an 'A', and may have been the name of the father. In addition, I'm pretty sure it was a fairly recent release--as in, since 2010.

I think that movie is: Listen... Amaya

Sounds like you're looking for Ankhon Dekhi ["Through My Own Eyes"] from 2014. From IMDb:

the lead character Bauji (Sanjay Mishra), in his late fifties, seeks answer to the very question of 'Truth'. He stays in an Old Delhi small house with his family as well as extended family. His exploration begins when an acquaintance gossips about Ajju, [a boy] of ill-repute with whom Bauji's daughter Rita (Maya Sarao) is in love. But Bauji finds Ajju to be just the opposite on meeting him. And that is when, Bauji's journey towards developing the Power of Discernment begins.

Bauji then decides that from now on, he'll only believe his own eyes, just like the film's title says. Here's the trailer:



